# Change language of UI elements on the fly in ios application

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, storyboard

I use the "Use base internationalization" in xcode 4.6.3. The project contains one storyboard file and few .stings files for localization storyboard into other languages.

I need to do to change language of UI elements on the fly. Exactly what I needed, implemented, for example, in the application "Booking.com". There is a static table with languages​​. When you press on cell, then UI elements instantly changed to the appropriate language. Moreover, elements changing not only in the current view, but also in other view controllers. This is important.

I tried to create the same UI (link for screenshot below) for testing as "Booking.com" app, but was unable to realize such localization system.

http://www.imagebam.com/image/15c901264635507

Google did not give the desired result. Please help me with the implementation of such localization system.

Comment: Can you please let us know what you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried to adapt this tutorial for my case http://aggressive-mediocrity.blogspot.ru/2010/03/custom-localization-system-for-your.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create your own localisation engine, and not to use the native one.
Create some manager, that holds the current language, and every time you want to load a string, send it to some function in this manager, and it will return the localised string.

The strings can be separated to files of course.